# how to turn off the Image creation in TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, tex4ebook

I don't want to reproduce the images as any format, like png, I need to turn off the options, For the equation, I am using the mathjax option

I run the file through

```
make4ht.exe -l -a debug -u -c mycfg.cfg <filename>.tex
```

and Texlive 2022

Help me to turn off the image generation

**MY CFG:**

```
\Preamble{xhtml,uni-html4,mathjax,charset=UTF-8,fn-in,NoFonts,ext=.xhtml}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,multirow,graphics,graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig2}
\caption{$y=5/x$}
\label{fig:five over x}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What figure generation do you get for this sample? There is only `fig2.png` which you explicitly requested using the `\includegraphics` command. The math in caption is kept as LaTeX source thanks to the MathJax option.